# (C) Implementation tactics for heap allocators?

Tags: c, performance, implementation, heapalloc

Where are some good resources for looking at the pros/cons of different ways of implementing heap allocators? Resources touching on efficiency (fragmentation, throughput, etc) are preferred. I am NOT looking for simple code repositories.

**edit:**

I'm not really interested in the philosophical grounding of this wiki. As such, I don't really want to get into 'why' I'm interested in this. Regardless of the underlying intentions/problems/etc, this information exists, so if you know of any good resources, please link to them here!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Arbitrarily replacing the CRT version is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very old problem, and to get a comprehensive view you will have to dig through the research literature.  (I'm not aware of a good textbook treatment.)

A few places to start:

- [Doug Lea's description of his memory allocator](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html)
- [*The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1*](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html) by Don Knuth
- [Quick fit: an efficient algorithm for heap storage allocation](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=51619&dl=GUIDE&coll=GUIDE&CFID=90294047&CFTOKEN=67034079) by Weinstock and Wulf

This one is worth spending a day in the library.  Yes, a big building full of paper—the problem is that old.

Comment: how well respected is doug lea's implementation? with the user of header and footer blocks for size of used blocks, and further pointer information for free blocks? has this strategy resulted in a good balance between fragmentation and time to service requests?

Comment: also, is the first version of "The Art of Programming" available free on that website? i can't find a copy.

Comment: @hatorade: Knuth is worth buying.

Comment: @hatorade: Lea's allocator is *highly* respected, and Don isn't likely to give away his life's work for free.  He's retired from Stanford and  book royalties are his income.